# could not load file or assembly ' microsoft.reportviewer.Common version=11.0.0.0'

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

Using reportviewer in my project . i face the following error message

**could not load file or assembly ' microsoft.reportviewer.Common version=11.0.0.0'**

Comment: http://www.nuget.org/packages/MicosoftReportViewerWebForms_v11/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the project ran fine on the local machine (in VS2012).  But when I published it, it wasn't working.  I got the yellow screen with the same issue as the original poster.

I followed the advice from @pravprab and ran the Package Manager for Report Viewer:   http://www.nuget.org/packages/MicosoftReportViewerWebForms_v11/

When I recompiled my project, the Report Viewer DLL showed up in the bin.

Then, when I published, the DLL was there, and the site works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Microsoft.ReportViewer.2012.Runtime* that contains `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms`, `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common` and `Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel` libraries. For more information please have a look at my answer on [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253607/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-reportviewer-common-version-11-0-0-0).